# How to position the footer at the bottom of the page or underneath the content

Tags: html, css, position, footer

I'd like my footer to be at the bottom of the page all time, because my pages aren't that long.

But when a page is longer than the screen, it needs to be underneath the content like a proper footer and not stuck at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help;

[jQuery Sticky Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/)

[demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStickyFooter/)

Answer (score 0):

If your footer has a fixed height, the most simple and CSS-only solution is this:

**CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    /* height of the footer */
    margin: 0 0 120px 0;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 120px;
}
```

**DEMO**

- [Try it with short content](http://jsfiddle.net/5QBQ3/)
- [Try it with a lot of content](http://jsfiddle.net/yGKKQ/)